# Bind object properties to another object's properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, javascript-objects

I want to create a new object, assign its property some values from another object and I want to 'bind' it - like pass by reference in C++.

So in this example below:

```
var object1 = {
    'obj1' : {
    'obj1a' : 'a',
    'obj1b' : 'b'
  },
  'obj2' : {
    'obj2c' : 'c',
    'obj2d' : 'd'
  }
}

var assignObject = {}
assignObject['obj1a'] = object1['obj1']['obj1a']
assignObject['obj1a'] = 'bbb'

console.log('assignObject' + JSON.stringify(assignObject))
console.log('object1' + JSON.stringify(object1))
```

Whenever I modify content of `assignObject['obj1a']`, I want it to reflect on `object1['obj1']['obj1a']` as well.

```
var assignObject = {}
assignObject['obj1a'] = object1['obj1']['obj1a']  // this is my idea of 'binding'
assignObject['obj1a'] = 'bbb'  // and updating of assignObject['obj1a']
```

Console prints:

```
assignObject{"obj1a":"bbb"}
object1{"obj1":{"obj1a":"a","obj1b":"b"},"obj2":{"obj2c":"c","obj2d":"d"}}
```

And I want it to print:

```
assignObject{"obj1a":"bbb"}
object1{"obj1":{"obj1a":"bbb","obj1b":"b"},"obj2":{"obj2c":"c","obj2d":"d"}}
```

How can I do this in Javascript?  Do note that there will be multiple parameters and they will be dynamic in real code (undefined depth nested objects).

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ha2qcdko/

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, not gonna happen like that. You might want to look into defining `obj1a` as a *getter* on `assignObject` so it evaluates its value anew every time it's accessed…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the `object` reference, it will work as you expect:

```
const object1 = {
  'obj1' : {
    'obj1a' : 'a',
    'obj1b' : 'b'
  },
  'obj2' : {
    'obj2c' : 'c',
    'obj2d' : 'd'
  }
}

let assignObject = object1.obj1;
assignObject.obj1a = "bbb";

console.log(object1);
```

But once your reference is `object1['obj1']['obj1a']`, that is not an `object` anymore, it is a `string`.